# How to get rid of warning Passing raw CLI options to `new Server(config, done)` is deprecated

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular-test

I recently upgraded Karma in my Angular app to v6.3.2. I am running Angular v11.

When I start my tests, I keep getting the message

> Passing raw CLI options to `new Server(config, done)` is deprecated. Use `parseConfig(configFilePath, cliOptions, {promiseConfig: true, throwErrors: true})` to prepare a processed `Config` instance and pass that as the `config` argument instead.

The tests run successfully

Below is my Karma configuration

```js
// Karma.conf.js
const plugins = [
  require( 'karma-jasmine' ),
  require( 'karma-chrome-launcher' ),
  require( 'karma-jasmine-html-reporter' ),
  require( 'karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter' ),
  require( '@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma' ),
  require( 'karma-verbose-reporter')
];
const ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox = {
  base: 'ChromeHeadless',
  flags: [ '--no-sandbox' ]
};
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins,
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'verbose'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_WARN,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: [ 'Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless', 'ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

How do I remove the deprecated feature being warned about?

Answer (score 18):

This issue has been already [reported](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20479) and [fixed](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/20485), but unfortunately only for Angular 12.